# Bot Framework with Table Storage started throwing an exception

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, azure-bot-service

Up until two days ago, I have been running the bot framework using Table Storage for my bot data based on this blog post [Saving State data with Bot Builder for Azure][1]

As of yesterday, I started getting the following error while running the bot

**

```
Exception: Buffer cannot be null. Parameter name: buffer
[File of type 'text/plain']
```

**

I have tracked it down to the following line of code in Global.asax.cs file

```
builder.Register(c => new CachingBotDataStore(store, CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy.ETagBasedConsistency)).As<IBotDataStore<BotData>>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

if I comment out that line, the bot runs, however, bot storage is not stored in the table anymore.

I have also implemented DocumentDB as a test, and the bot functions properly, but this would mean losing all of my user's state.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of the BotBuilder sdk are you using?

Comment: Bot.Builder Version 3.13.1

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this exception.  Does this error occur if you downgrade the sdk version to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/3.12.2.4 ?

Comment: Downgrading to 3.12.2.4 doesn't even kick off the controller, it throws an exception within the emulator console with the following

     [18:48:33] -> POST Request to 'http://localhost:3979/api/messages' failed: [500] Internal Server Error

Comment: The only thing I can think of is this change: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/commit/46c833e031ee1785673bffb42a1b417828dee0d4#diff-eb7876b7fd8cd7dc9d7902f152a5fd98 that was mistakenly released in v3.13.0.3 and reverted with https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/pull/4123/commits/f755bc6240845662e50e8aea21d11efe906e4450#diff-eb7876b7fd8cd7dc9d7902f152a5fd98 in v3.13.1  if you had used v3.13.0.3 with the emulator, there could be corrupted records in BotData for the 'default-user'.  Have you tried manually removing the state data records from table storage for the emulator ?

Comment: Please continue the conversation here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4179